# how can I destructure from an array of objects when data is coming from database dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

```
// foodItems is an array of object where one of it's key is id.

const [id1, id2, id3] = foodItems.map((item) => item.id);
// console.log(id1, id2, id3);
```

I can get id's by destructuring when array is static by doing above's code. But, How can I get the same id's when the data is coming from database dynamically in this array?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the array is static*"? Destructuring works exactly the same regardless where the array is coming from. Of course, if your database returns an array with an unknown number of elements, then destructuring just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have json from backend. The structure of that object is like this.
`"{"breakfast": [{breakfast items details}],"lunch": [{lunch items details}],"dinner": [{dinner items details}]}"
//I needed all meals items into an array so that I can easily traverse it. 

const mealItems = Object.values(foods);
const foodItems = mealItems.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    curr.map((item) => acc.push(item));
    return acc;
  }, []);
  console.log(foodItems);`

foodItems is the array here. I want to grab specific id for Add to cart button handler where I will handle this items to add in the cart. @xtj7

Comment: `const foodItems = mealItems.reduce((acc, curr) => {     curr.map((item) => acc.push(item));     return acc;   }, []);` can (should) be simplified to jut `const foodItems = mealItems.flat();`. But either way, destructuring seems not applicable here, just use a normal loop to find the specific id.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to solve this problem in a complicated way. But in that case, seems that I was with wrong approach. However, I learnt some new things. Again, Thank you guys for your time and I appreciate it from the core of my hearts.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: As Bergi pointed out: this horrible abomination does not even work if used in a different scope than root. But again, even if it had worked, don't do it like that.

Can you try to explain what you are really trying to do with that? Then we might be able to suggest a proper solution.

Old answer for historical reasons:

<s>I don't really know you use-case for this but it generally seems like a bad idea. This is a poor pattern, do not use it, but it should answer your question anyways. So here is an example:</s>

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach((data, i) => {
  this[`id${i+1}`] = data
})
```

Would lead to this:

```
id1: a
id2: b
id3: c
```

For your specific code, assuming the object has an "id" column that should be used (which would still prefix the variable with "id"):

```
foodItems.forEach((data) => {
  this[`id${data.id}`] = data
})
```

Assuming an object like
`const foodItems = [{id: 'foo', value: 'bar'}]`, it would result in this:

```
idfoo: {id: 'foo', value: 'bar'}
```

If you can provide some more context, maybe we could come up with a better solution that actually helps you?

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: Technically a way to dynamically destructure data and answering the question. In actual fact a horrible abomination that should never be used.

Comment: No it does not "dynamically destructure", it *creates* a structure by adding properties to an object. But it's not clear which object that is supposed to be - `this` is `undefined` in normal functions.

Comment: Only if you pass functions as a parameter, otherwise `this` is defined and it works as expected. And by adding the elements to `this`, they become available as regular values within the scope. Go ahead and give it a try. Again, hacky and not ever to be used, but it does work: https://jsfiddle.net/ck3jda8t/1/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*if you pass functions as a parameter*". I refer to a regular strict-mode function that is called without a specific receiver, [which doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/7h1q8xbc/). Which object do you **want** `this` to refer to? **How** do the properties "*become available as regular values within the scope*"?

Comment: I mean, sure, easy enough to tweak it to work in strict mode: https://jsfiddle.net/medx9y1w/ - but again: anything in the local scope is also available on `this`. And that's why the "solution" works, because the reverse is also true: anything added to `this` will become available as a regular variable in the scope too.

Comment: "*anything in the local scope is also available on `this`*" - no, absolutely not. The `this` keyword in all your examples refers to the global object. Sure, properties on that become available as **global** variables, but the `this` keyword has nothing to do with the local scope whatsoever.

Comment: Well, lesson learned, I shouldn't try to be a smartass on stackoverflow at 4am. You are of course absolutely correct. I am also not going to make my horrible "solution" even worse by using eval. I will edit my answer but leave it here, maybe someone else can learn from it. Apologies for being so adamant about wrong code.